# How many trials of n samples where each value was sampled at least once

Tags: sample

I have a bag of 60 marbles(N=60). I can only examine 30 random marbles (n=30) at a time. After each trial, I replace the sampled marbles back in the bag. 
How many trials will it take for me to examine each marble at least one time?

Comment: Change "424" to "60" and "5" to "30" to convert the duplicate into this question.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something here, there is no **finite** number of trials that will guarantee you see each marble at least once.

Since you replace the marbles after each sample, then hypothetically speaking if you took $x$ number of samples, you could sample the same exact marbles all $x$ times with positive probability.

If you were to take an **infinite** number of samples however, the probability of never getting any one marble would go to zero, and so you'd get every marble at least once with probability one.